# why the Oracle support Concatenation Operator "||" write as "| |"?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

The **Oracle SQL** support Concatenation Operator `||` write as `| |`,
which means there is a blank space between two solid vertical bars.
Dose it may confused the tokenizer?

`SELECT col1||col2||col3||col4 "Concatenation" FROM tab1;` is working.

so dose `SELECT col1| |col2| |col3| |col4 "Concatenation" FROM tab1;`.

Comment: A bit odd. I'd still keep them together, who knows what happens in next Oracle version. (Also, avoid quirkiness to be portable.)

Comment: Both options work. Didn't even know that `| |` exists & works.